# c# indefinte Task continue execution on exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have started to explore `TPL` in `.NET` to implement a windows service which will run multiple independent methods in parallel with some delay after each successful execution, following is a rough console application I came up with after looking at various examples:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource _ct1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationTokenSource _ct2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        int count = 0;
        var task1 = new Task(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    DoWork();
                    await Task.Delay(2000, _ct1.Token);
                    count++;
                    if (count >= 5)
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                //Log cancellation and do not continue execution
                Console.WriteLine("DoWork cancelled: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log error and continue with execution
                Console.WriteLine("Error occurred at DoWork");
            }
        }, _ct1.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        var task2 = new Task(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    DoWork2();
                    await Task.Delay(2000, _ct2.Token);
                    count++;
                    if (count >= 5)
                    {
                        _ct2.Cancel();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                //Log cancellation and do not continue execution
                Console.WriteLine("DoWork2 cancelled: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log error and continue with execution
                Console.WriteLine("Error occurred at DoWork");
            }
        }, _ct2.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something...");
    }

    public static void DoWork2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something else...");
    }
}
```

In the above code when any exception occurs during the task execution, I need to log the error and then continue with the task execution, right now the task stops executing if there is an exception. My questions:

1. How to handle exceptions properly so that the task execution doesn't stop?
2. When I add a debugger break point at `DoWork()` method, the `DoWork2()` doesn't run which mean the tasks are not running in parallel on separate threads and running on a single thread and blocking each other. How to make sure the `Tasks` are running independent of each other on separate threads?

PS: The above code is a simple console app just to understand the workings of TPL, so please ignore if there are obvious design problems.

Comment: If an exception has caused a task to end, then that's it - there's no way to make it continue. You have to handle the exceptions *inside* the task's code. You could start the task again, but I question what this would gain you if the exception was something like `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`...

Comment: The reason debugger is not running code in DoWork2() is because in the above code I don't see any line which is starting task2.

Comment: If you want long running activities that do not produce any meaningful results in and of themselves, it sounds like what you need are *threads*, not *tasks*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is exactly what I need to do...What is the difference between `Thread` and `Task` for my requirement?. I checked the `ThreadId` using the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` property for `DoWork()` and `DoWork2()` methods and the id's are different which means the tasks are running on different threads so there is no need to explicitly create threads and manage them...

Comment: @pull420 missed out that line of code when copying, edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the simplest chage you can do to make your task1 running after exception is as follows:

```
var task1 = new Task(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            DoWork();
            await Task.Delay(2000, _ct1.Token);
            count++;
            if (count >= 5)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            //Log cancellation and do not continue execution
            Console.WriteLine("DoWork cancelled: " + ex.Message);
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log error and continue with execution
            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred at DoWork");
            count = 0;  //  without this you'll have exception thrown on each of further iterations
        }
    }
}, _ct1.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Meaning that try...catch is moved inside the loop.

Please also note @pull420 comment on while you don't see task2 running